# How do i create a script to locate a public ip address of a network computer?

Tags: scripts

I am really struggling to find the solution to this problem. I would really appreciate It if you guys could put the script in nano.

Comment: Please do not post [the very same question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1090366/504066) twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to get the public IP address, you only need this command `curl ipinfo.io/ip`
But if you want to use a shell script, follow these steps:

- run this command in the terminal `nano script.sh`
- put these lines in your script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  curl ipinfo.io/ip
  ```
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> , then <kbd>y</kbd> to save the changes.
- run `chmod +x script.sh` to make your script executable

To run the script use:

```
./script.sh
```

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. I'll change it. Thank you!